# List items with alternating colors

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list view and an adapter that sets alternating background colors to the list items ("zebra" list style):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    ...
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
    return convertView;
}
```

But now, when i select an item using scroll wheel, or when I click an item, the original colors for selecting/clicking do not override my custom backgrounds (I can see the original color below the one I set).

How can I set the original colors for these states?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create two selectors which are used as the background resources, with transparent color in the state_selected mode:
(res/drawable/alterselector1.xml:)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/altercolor1"/>

</selector>
```

(res/drawable/alterselector2.xml:)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/altercolor2"/>
</selector>
```

(res/values/colors.xml:)

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="transparent">#00ffffff</drawable>
    <drawable name="altercolor1">#ffffffff</drawable>
    <drawable name="altercolor2">#ff000000</drawable>
</resources>
```

Then you set the backgrounds in the getView method of the adapter with the setBackgroundResource method:

```
if (position % 2 == 0){
    reusableView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alterselector1);
} else {
    reusableView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alterselector2);
}
```

Now when you select a row, your background don't hide the original selector behind.

Comment: This works partially - I can see highlight when item is focused using scroll button, but I can't make it work when item is pressed. I tried all the states listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html, but nothing worked...

Comment: I have edited the selectors to handle the pressed state too. Seems like when you press the item, it loses it's selected state. So you have to define the pressed state to be transparent too. Just take care for the ordering, because the selector will use the first item that matches the current state, so the state_selected="false" item should be at the bottom.

Comment: Works! Almost a year since I asked this question!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your list highlight color
if you do it via styles

```
 <style name="Widget.AbsListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/my_selector</item>
 </style>
```

or you can set same attribute in code
my_selector is a state drawable - look for examples in the SDK directory :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

</selector>
```

Comment: I tried that, but whatever I set for the background at first, gets overridden by creating "zebra" in the code after... Is there another way to create zebra look?