# Alternate Background Color on a TableRow

Tags: android, tableview, tablerow

I have a TableView that adds a TableRow for each entry in an XML file that it parses from.

To set the background color, I am currently using:

`TableRow.setBackgroundResource(color);`

How can I set it so each TableRow alternates background colors?

Comment: Similar to [List Items with Alternating Colors.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050533/list-items-with-alternating-colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and straightforward solution could be, as you iterate over each entry in the XML file, keep a counter. If the counter is odd, use `color1`, if the counter is even, use `color2`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_XML_ENTRIES; i++){
  // add table row
  if (i % 2) {
    TableRow.setBackgroundResource(color1);
  } else {
    TableRow.setBackgroundResource(color2);
  }
}
```