# list item row color issue android

Tags: android, list, click

I have implemented custom adapter for list items. I have two requirements

1) list items should have alternate colors. To implement that, i have below code

```
private final int[] bgColors = new int[] {R.color.list_bg_1, R.color.list_bg_2};            
int colorPosition = position % bgColors.length;
convertView.setBackgroundResource(bgColors[colorPosition]);
```

2) when you click on list item, it should highlight

```
Drawable selectedBackground;
  selectedBackground = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.backgroundColor);
    if (selectedPos == position) {
                convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(selectedBackground);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            }

// this method is called in onItemClick in Activity.
 public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
            selectedPos = pos;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Problem: when I put both code, either of the functionality doesn't work. How can I make sure that both functionality works with above code?

Comment: See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050533/list-items-with-alternating-colors)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a selector.xml file for the background and then set the background of the view to that selector name. The selector lets you choose a background for each state of the view; whether or not the view is selected, pressed, etc.

i.e.,
You have a xml file called my_views_background_selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selectedBackground" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressedBackground" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/regularBackground"/>


</selector>
```

And then you can either set the background programatically by doing

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_views_background_selector)
```

Or in the xml file that you used to inflate your convertedView